# как отобразить MEMO в DBGrid?

Tags: delphi

Нашел [эту](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm) статью. Там написано что надо открыть Column Editor в DBGrid, выбрать нужное поле, перейти на вкладку Events и выбрать событие OnGetText. Но у меня его нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю? Или может есть какой-нибудь другой способ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно открывать не DBGrid'овский Column editor, а DataSet'овский Fields Editor.
2. Допустим, БД - Access. В таблице есть поле "M" типа "поле MEMO".

   - Кидаешь на форму ADOQuery
   - Пишешь запрос
   - Подключаешься
   - Открываешь Fields editor
   - Добавляешь поле "M" (не создаёшь, а именно добавляешь), оно уже будет иметь тип TMemoField
   - Для этого поля пишешь обработчик

Однако, если текст многострочный, то придётся ещё свою отрисовку текста делать или использовать другой грид.

Answer (score 0):

- Connect your TDataset descendant component (TTable, TQuery,
  TADOTable, TADOQuery ....) to the "TestTable" database table.
- Double click the dataset component to open the Fields editor
- Add the MEMO field to the list of persistent fields
- Select the MEMO field in the Fields editor
- Activate the Events tab in the Object Inspector
- Double click the OnGetText event to create the event handler

Там написано даблклик на набор данных (TTable, TQuery, TADOTable, TADOQuery ....) и в редакторе полей выбрать поле MEMO. Про DBGrid там нет ни слова. Причём это поле MEMO предварительно необходимо ещё и создать.